# Json File to proto

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a json file which I want to convert to proto java file.

Is there any direct way of doing so ?

I have tried reading the file into string and then converting the string to proto messge , but failed to do so , I keep getting

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: JsonObject
```

at         `JsonFormat.parser().usingTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry.getEmptyTypeRegistry()).merge(jsonConfig, messageBuilder);`

here is my json:

```
{
    "a": 123,
    "b": {
        "b1": [
            {
                "id": "123"
            }
        ]
    },
    "c": 30,
    "d": [
        "d1",
        "d2"
    ],
    "e": [
        {
            "e1": "ads",
                "e2": "asd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
JsonFormat.parser().merge(json, request);
```